# Regex pattern get specific text from url

Tags: regex

How can i use regex to get the keyword appName from possible url string like below

> i have tried this `/(?<=webapp/)(.*)(?=#)/g` but it only works with
>   example2 and example3

```
example1: http://localhost:1001/myapp/appName
example2: http://localhost:1001/myapp/appName#!/
example3: http://localhost:1001/myapp/appName#!/Test
example4: http://localhost:1001/myapp/appName/test/what
```

Comment: You can use: `/(?<=\/myapp\/)[\w-]+/`

Comment: Just modify it to [`/(?<=myapp\/).*?(?=(?:[#\/]|$))/g`](https://regex101.com/r/8neCrU/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=\/myapp\/)[^?#\/]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3OjUZN/1)

- `[^?#\/]+`: Match 1+ characters that are not in the character class i.e. `?,#,/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
    (\/myapp\/)(.*?)[^?#\/\n]+
    replace $2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `webapp` to `myapp`. If the "appName" consists of only word characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, you could use `\w+`:

[`(?<=myapp/)\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/c0Q13S/1)